# Does reinstallation of app delete SQLiteDatabase or SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sqlite, backup, sharedpreferences, restore

I wanted to know whether reinstallation of app deletes SQLiteDatabase or SharedPreferences in Android. Also under what circumstances does it gets deleted. Application will be downloaded from server & installed. If it does get deleted what should we do to take a backup & restore it again?

Please help...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No... Database and SharedPreferences will not be deleted if one reinstall the app. They get deleted when some one uninstall it or clear data from settings menu of device...

Answer (score 5):

Updating your app (installing newer or the same version) will keep you preferences and all data, unless you do not intentionally delete them in your code..
But if you uninstall the app before installing it again, then yes, all your data will be gone..

In Android Debug Bridge you can specify whether should you install it over the existing installation, or do a clean install with the -r flag (`adb install your.apk` / `adb install -r your.apk`)

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` and `SQLiteDatabase` are deleted when you

- uninstall your app.
- clear data(from settings).

If you want to restore your `SharedPreferences` and `SQLiteDatabase` when your app is **reinstalled** then you should add a `BackupAgentHelper` to your app. Together with the `SharedPreferenceBackupHelper`, it backups the `SharedPreferences` and `SQLiteDatabase` to the cloud *(if the device supports it)*. When the app is reinstalled the data is restored.

See:

[BackupAgentHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgentHelper.html)
[SharedPreferenceHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html) (contains all the code you need to implement it)
[general Backup guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)

Just let me know if it worked for you. Hope it Helps :) Cheers.