# Is sharedPreference cleared when an android app is reinstalled?

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite, android-install-apk

When we run an app during development on a device is sharedPreference cleared when app is reinstalled ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does reinstallation of app delete SQLiteDatabase or SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628454/does-reinstallation-of-app-delete-sqlitedatabase-or-sharedpreferences)

Comment: `Is sharedPreference cleared when app is reinstalled ?  :` Yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- If the app is manually uninstalled first and then reinstalled, then
  yes, `SharedPreference`s and SQLite tables of the old installation
  are deleted.
- If the app is updated from the Play Store or re-run from the IDE
  without uninstalling the previous version of app first, then
  `SharedPreference`s and SQLite tables of the old installation are
  still present.

Comment: and what will happen if I get the msg "the app is already installed, Do you want to uninstall the previously installed app and install it again" (something similar I get when I try to run my app which has an old build already running on my device through eclipse run) ?

Comment: then the previous version of the app will be uninstalled first, the SQLite and SharedPreferences will be deleted and the new version will then be installed.

Comment: Hmm, I am a little doubtful on this case. I think even in this case the sharedPreference will remain. I will check it once in code just to be sure. Thanks for the answer

Comment: The best way is always to uninstall the app manually to be sure that previous data is deleted :)

Comment: I have already upvoted the answer, just waiting to get in front of my mac to test the second case :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71665/discussion-between-avijeet-and-zygoteinit).

Answer (score 0):

If you will clear the data of an application then the shared preference will 
be cleared hence if you reinstall an application for the first time there will
be no application data so no shared preference will be there.

Answer (score 0):

while reinstalling the app,shared preference never clear. While un installed and installing the app. Shared preference get cleared.